# res.data is sending me back an object at the end of the json array

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm experiencing a weird response from a server api.
When I'm logging the res.data,this is the structure I got back:

```
[
{
"id": "3",
"name": "Jack"

},
{
"id": "4",
"name": "Paul"
}

]
{
    "timestamp": 1626798750349,
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "path": "/api/logs/documents/323232"
}
```

Do you guys have any idea why that object was appended here at the end, preventing me to iterate through the res.data? There is a way from the front end to get rid of it with a regex expression?
Thanks

Comment: This is not valid json. Anyway, it's not a weird response at all. It's not uncommon to see API's return some metadata about your API calls, for example pagination information or in this case, details such as timestamp and status code. You should not try to remove this with regex (very prone to errors for this sort of thing), but rather, only parse that specific part of the JSON which you will be using.

Comment: It' weird because I'm working with this API since long and I never had this issue with the other calls. I usually get the res.data parsed by react When I'm setting the response into the state. I can't get access to the backend API, So I would need to find a way on the front end.

Comment: Is this your entire response json? It doesn't look valid and a JSON validator has confirmed that it's invalid, so unless the API you are using is doing some ...funky.. stuff, there seems to be some JSON missing

Comment: I can't disclose the exact call but yes, that's the structure I got back from Postman: [{},{},{}] {}